# How to introspect a Click application?

Tags: python, click

I have a Click app called "DC" starting with click.Group `cli()`, which has many subcommands. I'm trying to produce a text file with a list of all commands, arguments, options, and help text as a convenient reference. How do I introspect a Click application?

I experimented using the [API reference](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/api/#commands), but it's confusing.  Some of Command's methods (like `get_usage()`) require a "context" object as the first arg, and I only know two ways to get one:

1. Be inside a command with `@pass_context` decorator.  *(Not always the case.)*
2. Call `click.get_current_context()` to get the "current" context, which seems to be the one attached to the bottom-level command that is currently being executed.

That *seemed* to work:

```
from dc.__main__ import cli

current_ctx = click.get_current_context()
click.echo(cli.get_usage(current_ctx))
```

This prints the docstring from the `cli()` function.  However, if I try to inspect the list of subcommands:

```
click.echo(cli.commands)
```

I get an empty dict. After more exploring, I finally managed to find my way to the real data by doing this:

```
current_ctx.find_root().command.commands
```

which returned a dict with all the top-level commands I expected to see.

Is that the preferred method?

Answer (score 0):

With python 3.9 and click 7.1.2 I got it working like so:

```py
import click

@click.group()
def cli():
    """
    Command line interface for greatest application ever.
    """
    pass


# Add your groups here...


# Different separators for each level.
level_sep = {
    1: "\n" + "="*80 + "\n",
    2: "-"*80,
    3: "- "*40,
    4: "-  "*26,
    5: "-   "*20,
}


def print_level(cmd, cmd_name, level=0, indentation='  ', max_depth=5):
    """
    Prints the help string of a group or command.

    :param cmd: The command or group to print.
    :param cmd_name: The name of the command or group.
    :param level: The nesting level of the command or group.
    :param indentation: The characters used for padding.
    :param max_depth: The maximum depth to print.
    """

    # Print a separator for all levels except the first.
    if level:
        click.echo(level_sep.get(level, ""))

    # Get the standard help for the command, splitted in lines.
    cmd_help = cmd.get_help(click.Context(cmd)).splitlines()

    # Replace usage in first line with the full command.
    cmd_help[0] = cmd_help[0].replace(
        'Usage: ', cmd_name
    )

    # Indent all lines by some spaces per level.
    click.echo('\n'.join([
        indentation*level + l for l in cmd_help
    ]))

    # If the command is a group, print its subcommands.
    if hasattr(cmd, 'commands') and (level+1) < max_depth:
        for sub_cmd_name, sub_cmd in cmd.commands.items():
            print_level(
                sub_cmd,
                f'{cmd_name} {sub_cmd_name}',
                level=level+1,
                max_depth=max_depth
            )


@click.command()
@click.option(
    '-d', '--depth', default=5,
    help='The depth of the nested groups to explore.',
    type=int
)
def help(depth: int = 5):
    """
    Prints the entire help.

    It includes the help for top level command and nested
    groups and commands up to the specified depth (
    1 means print only top help, 2 means print top commands
    and its groups and so on; default is 5).
    """
    import sys
    import os
    print_level(cli, os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]), max_depth=depth)
    click.echo(level_sep[1])


cli.add_command(help)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

The `commands` member of the `Group` class is documented [here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/api/#click.Group.commands) for click version 7 and [here](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.0.x/api/#click.Group.commands) for click version 8.